# Criação correta das tabelas

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Dadas as minhas classes onde `Encomenda` herda de `Objeto`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "objeto")
@XmlRootElement(name = "objeto")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Objeto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-z]{2}\\d{9}[A-z]{2}", message = "O código não é válido")
    @Size(min = 13, max = 13, message = "Apenas 13 caracteres")
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 13, unique = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Nome não pode estar em branco")
    @XmlElement(name = "numero")
    private String codigo;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "evento")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objeto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Evento> eventos;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement
    @Column
    private String erro;

}
```

Encomenda:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Encomenda extends Objeto {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlTransient
    private String local;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlTransient
    private String descricao;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlTransient
    private String evento;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlTransient
    private String loja;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlTransient
    private Timestamp horaEvento;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column
    @XmlTransient
    private String situacao;

}
```

O que está acontecendo é que quando as tabelas são criadas no banco, a tabela objeto está com todos os campos de encomenda, como posso corrigir ? Quero só os campos da classe Objeto na tabela objeto. Já a tabela encomenda quero campos de ambas as classes, até aí tudo bem, o que preciso é replicar os mesmos valores que estão em objeto nos campos de encomenda, como fazer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

para este caso você deve adotar a tabela por SubClasse,faça o seguinte:

- Adicione na classe objeto:
   @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
- Na classe encomenda:
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")

Desta forma você terá as tabelas separadas. Tenha cuidado somente com a questão de performance com muitas heranças, o que poderá afetar o desempenho do seu software.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.